# Strange bottom margin (or space) in mobile menu when adding desktop layout

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, codepen

I was designing a mobile menu for a website (using codepen). The desktop layout for the menu had already been written.

The mobile layout was written and works just fine as intended. However after adding the desktop layout, there appears a strange space at the bottom of the menu in the mobile layout. The desktop layout remains unchanged.

The layout can be found over at: https://codepen.io/pcassima/pen/ZgWYOd
this includes only the HTML and style for the menu.

I have already tried commenting out the padding, and margins in the desktop layout, but this does not remove the space.

I expect there to be no space at the bottom of the menu bar in the mobile menu.

```js
function hamburgerNav() {
  // Get the navigation list from the page
  let nav_list = document.getElementById("nav-list");
  // Get the hamburger from the page (to change the shape)
  let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");

  // Add or remove the active class from the navigation list
  if (nav_list.classList.contains("active")) {
    nav_list.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
    nav_list.classList.add("active");
  }
  // Add or remove the active class from the hamburger
  if (hamburger.classList.contains("active")) {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
    hamburger.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  /* Unsetting the margin and padding for everything */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* Setting the global font */
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}


/* Desktop layout */

nav {
  /* The global navigation container for the hamburger and navigation*/
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0 rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.64);
  background-color: #20dce1;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav .hamburger {
  /* In desktop mode hide the hamburger */
  display: none;
}

.top-navbar {
  /* The container for the actual navigation */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.nav-list {
  /* The unordered list for the navigation links */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-list li {
  /* The menu list items */
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

nav a {
  /* styles for the menu links */
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-top-accent {
  /* The top accents for the menu links (for the desktop view) */
  background-color: #e11c84;
  height: 4px;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-list li:hover .nav-top-accent,
.nav-list .nav-active .nav-top-accent {
  /* Scaling the top accent bar for hover and the active link (current page)   */
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  /* Mobile layout */
  nav .top-navbar {
    /* The container for the actual navigation */
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    /* The menu list items */
    /* Unsetting the float, from the desktop layout */
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
  }
  nav .nav-top-accent {
    /* The top accents for the menu links (for the desktop view) */
    display: none;
  }
  nav a {
    /* styles for the menu links */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav .nav-active {
    /* The active menu link (the current page) */
    background-color: #e11c84;
  }
  nav .nav-list {
    /* The default display is none (inactive) */
    display: none;
  }
  nav .nav-list.active {
    /* When the menu becomes active, display the menu links */
    display: block;
  }
  nav .hamburger {
    /* The container for the hamburger button */
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav .hamburger.active #h-bar1 {
    /* When the menu becomes active, rotate the top bar */
    transform: translate(0, 250%) rotate(45deg);
  }
  nav .hamburger.active #h-bar2 {
    /* When the menu becomes active, scale the bar in the x-direction to 0 */
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  nav .hamburger.active #h-bar3 {
    /* When the menu becomes active, rotate the bottom bar */
    transform: translate(0, -250%) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  nav .hamburger-bar {
    /* Styling for the individual bars for the hamburger */
    width: 40px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 6px 0;
    /* Animating the transistions */
    transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 style="text-align:center; font-size:38px;margin:16px;">responsive menu</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <!-- The construction for the hamburger (for mobile menus)-->
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger" onclick="hamburgerNav()">
      <div class="hamburger-bar" id="h-bar1"></div>
      <div class="hamburger-bar" id="h-bar2"></div>
      <div class="hamburger-bar" id="h-bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The actual nav-bar with the links-->
    <div class="top-navbar">
      <ul class="nav-list" id="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-active">
          <div class="nav-top-accent"></div>
          <a href="index.html">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="nav-top-accent"></div>
          <a href="#">projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="nav-top-accent"></div>
          <a href="#">tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="nav-top-accent"></div>
          <a href="#">about</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="nav-top-accent"></div>
          <a href="#">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <h1 style="margin:8px;">A responsive menu</h1>
  <p style="margin:8px;">A responsive menu for mobile and desktop. On desktop the menu has a hover animation, while on mobile there is an animated hamburger button to open the menu.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct then if you remove the display inline-block on the .top-navbar class you should visually see that the space is gone/removed.

FYI: you only should remove this when your mobile menu is active. On the desktop version this is still necessary.

Comment: That was correct! I added display:block; to the .top-navbar class in the mobile view and now everything is working correctly again. Thank you for your help!